# Access to Remote Desktop in Windows Server without RDS CAL's

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

Suppose we have Windows Server 2008 R2 without any RDS CAL's.
Is it possible to give access to Remote Desktop to a user which is not in 'Administrators' group ? 
I've tried everything and it seems that it is not, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Did you try adding the user in question to the Remote Desktop users Group? That should work even on regular old limit 2 sessions non-licensed servers.

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Add the non-Administrator users that need Remote Desktop access to the "Remote Desktop Users" group on the server.

Comment: I've tried that. It does not work. I'm still getting notice that I have no rights to log in.

Comment: @Malloc4k, Can that user login at the console?

Comment: There are relevant troubleshooting steps here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2477176.  Based on the limited description of the problem, it's hard to tell if the root cause is user rights, RDP client security requirements, or perhaps a mis-configuration of the RDS or the firewall.

Comment: Btw, this non-admin user's password can not be blank!